# Why is shadowLastChange an unknown attr?

Tags: linux, openldap

I'm trying to install slapd on Oracle Linux 7 and I'm following the [Oracle® LinuxAdministrator's Guide for Release 7 section on Configuring an LDAP Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-s9-auth.html).  When I get to step 7, importing the config ldif, I get the error:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "olcDatabase=hdb,cn=config"
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: <olcAccess> handler exited with 1
```

When I run slapd in debug mode with:

```
/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h "ldapi:/// ldap:/// ldaps:///" -d 255
```

I see the following error indicating that the attr `shadowLastChange` is unknown.

```
58daa3a6 <<< dnPrettyNormal: <dc=ams,dc=sim,dc=mil>, <dc=ams,dc=sim,dc=mil>
58daa3a6 slapd: line 0: unknown attr "shadowLastChange" in to clause
58daa3a6 <access clause> ::= access to <what> [ by <who> [ <access> ] [ <control> ] ]+
<what> ::= * | dn[.<dnstyle>=<DN>] [filter=<filter>] [attrs=<attrspec>]
<attrspec> ::= <attrname> [val[/<matchingRule>][.<attrstyle>]=<value>] | <attrlist>
<attrlist> ::= <attr> [ , <attrlist> ]
<attr> ::= <attrname> | @<objectClass> | !<objectClass> | entry | children
<who> ::= [ * | anonymous | users | self | dn[.<dnstyle>]=<DN> ]
        [ realanonymous | realusers | realself | realdn[.<dnstyle>]=<DN> ]
        [dnattr=<attrname>]
        [realdnattr=<attrname>]
        [group[/<objectclass>[/<attrname>]][.<style>]=<group>]
        [peername[.<peernamestyle>]=<peer>] [sockname[.<style>]=<name>]
        [domain[.<domainstyle>]=<domain>] [sockurl[.<style>]=<url>]
        [dynacl/<name>[/<options>][.<dynstyle>][=<pattern>]]
        [ssf=<n>] [transport_ssf=<n>] [tls_ssf=<n>] [sasl_ssf=<n>]
<style> ::= exact | regex | base(Object)
<dnstyle> ::= base(Object) | one(level) | sub(tree) | children | exact | regex
<attrstyle> ::= exact | regex | base(Object) | one(level) | sub(tree) | children
<peernamestyle> ::= exact | regex | ip | ipv6 | path
<domainstyle> ::= exact | regex | base(Object) | sub(tree)
<access> ::= [[real]self]{<level>|<priv>}
<level> ::= none|disclose|auth|compare|search|read|{write|add|delete}|manage
<priv> ::= {=|+|-}{0|d|x|c|s|r|{w|a|z}|m}+
<control> ::= [ stop | continue | break ]
dynacl:
        <name>=ACI      <pattern>=<attrname>

58daa3a6 olcAccess: value #0: <olcAccess> handler exited with 1!
```

If I take the line:

```
olcAccess: to attrs=shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by * read
```

out, it works, but I'm wondering if the system is broken.  When I look for `shadowLastChange` in `/etc/openldap`, I see that it exists in `nis.ldif` and `nis.schema`.

```
$ grep -rn shadowLastChange /etc/openldap/
/etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif:36:olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange' EQUALITY integ
/etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif:89:  $ shadowLastChange $ shadowMin $ shadowMax $ shadowWarning $ shadowInactive
/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema:65:attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange'
/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema:171:    MAY ( userPassword $ shadowLastChange $ shadowMin $
```

Why is `shadowLastChange` unknown?  What do I need to do to get past this issue on the path to configuring `slapd` to be able to authenticate users?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `shadowLastChange` is not yet part of your server's schema as it doesn't show up in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={x}nis.ldif`.

Did you forget to add the advised lines to your ldif?

```
include file:///etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif

include file:///etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif

include file:///etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

Comment: No, I didn't forget to put that in the file, but I just realized that `include` should be followed by a ':' to make `include: file://...`  Oracle's documentation is incorrect.  Once corrected it works.  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.openldap.org/software//man.cgi?query=LDIF&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release#end

Comment: I posted a complete answer, not because I don't appreciate your help, but because it will be easier for others to find the correct answer if they go looking for the problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle® LinuxAdministrator's Guide for Release 7 section on Configuring an LDAP Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-s9-auth.html) has the user create an LDIF file in step 7.

```
# Load the schema files required for accounts
include file:///etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif

include file:///etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif

include file:///etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif

# Load the HDB (hierarchical database) backend modules
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
```

As shown in the [OpenLDAP man page for LDIF](http://www.openldap.org/software//man.cgi?query=LDIF&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release#end), the syntax for `include` requires it be followed by a colon.  Add colons to yield the following and shadowLastChange will exist as an attribute when executed in step 8.

```
# Load the schema files required for accounts
include: file:///etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif

include: file:///etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif

include: file:///etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif

# Load the HDB (hierarchical database) backend modules
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
```